What happens to a user's pending edits when they subsequently gain enough reputation for their edits to be applied without peer review?
For example, on the Law stack 1,000 reputation earns one a privilege so that

Edits to other users’ posts are applied immediately

And

In addition, users with this privilege level can also begin reviewing suggested edits.

But what about the edge case where a <1,000 user has edits awaiting review and then reaches that milestone?

Do they get automatically approved?

Or do they remain for review - and if so, will they be able to approve their own suggested edits?

And what about the +2 rep for an approved edit?  Would it be awarded despite passing the 1,000 mark?


